# Flat Battery, heath is down but charge is fine

Tags: battery-drain, battery-testing

yesterday, suddenly my car battery got flat, i was driving since one hour, i just stop on a shop and it didnt start again, i called the breakdown AA, they came and started my car, he said that  the car battery health is down that why you need to  change the battery but charging is full, that why it happened.

can anyone tel me the difference between the battery health and charging of battery as charged was full and health was down.

Load of Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Car batteries only last a certain length of time - average is about 5-6 years although it will depend on the climate and the type of use the car gets.

What the AA are telling you is that your battery is getting to the end of it's life - they fully charged it, but it won't keep that charge as well as it should do, especially in cold weather.

It's probably, therefore, time to get a new battery

Answer (score 0):

Take the battery back to where you bought it. They'll test it for free and sell sell you a new one if you need one. If they say it's good you need to perform normal vehicle maintenence required on all cars.